# Modifying camel routes/context during runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am using Apache camel as an integration framework in my application. I am using @ImportResource annotation to add CamelContext.xml file into my application. Like this the camel context file is taken from DB using another service.
`@ImportResource("http://IP:PORT/files/CamelContext.xml")`

Camel Context will look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd 
    ">
<import resource="http://IP:PORT/files/SampleTestFile.xml" />
<camelContext id="ModelIntegration" trace="true"
        messageHistory="true" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <routeContextRef ref="SampleTestRef" />
</camelContext>

</beans>
```

As the camel context is taken from another service via API I would like to add Route Management in my application as well. So I am planning to use APIs in the route managing service to update the routes and context file. But the confusion is how to reload/apply the new changes making to context and routes during runtime without restarting the application.
Someone please help with this.

HI @SpaceTrucker
This is the error occured when I done as u suggested

```
2023-04-28 13:08:41.622  WARN [model-service,cffe4a00955e7fb9,cffe4a00955e7fb9] 1424 --- [nio-8060-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [BufferPoolPruner-1-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@17.0.2/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1672)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1122)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
2023-04-28 13:08:41.626  WARN [model-service,cffe4a00955e7fb9,cffe4a00955e7fb9] 1424 --- [nio-8060-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Camel (ModelIntegration) thread #1 - file:///var/camelRoute/aqr/common/in23] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@17.0.2/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1672)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1062)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1122)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
 java.base@17.0.2/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

And my code is like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only way this is typically achieved in a spring application is to refresh the application context using `org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext.refresh()`. In order to avoid restarting your whole application with that the camel stuff should be in it's own application context which might have the applications overall context as a parent. Then you are only restarting the stuff that is necessary.

Note that runtime route management and more is already part of of [camel-karaf](https://camel.apache.org/camel-karaf/3.20.x/index.html). So instead of reinventing the wheel you might want to investigate moving the camel stuff to a karaf instance.

Comment: Hi @SpaceTrucker ,
I had tried using this but the refresh function call is causing the application to crash mentioning that some threads are started and has failed to stop it, this may cause memory leak.
Can you help with this.

Comment: @Abhi this might warrant it's own question if you are able to provide the complete error details and an MCVE.

Comment: Hi @SpaceTrucker, I am getting the below error. 2023-04-28 13:08:41.626 WARN [model-service,cffe4a00955e7fb9,cffe4a00955e7fb9] 1424 --- [nio-8060-exec-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Camel (ModelIntegration) thread #1 - file:///var/camelRoute/aqr/common/in23] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Will edit the question and add more information there, Please find out and help